# How to get localhost/foldername url in localhost

Tags: php

I setup folder in localhost. I want to write a script to get that domain path but I've tried using

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] 
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] 
getenv('HTTP_HOST')
```

these all given `http://localhost` only , how could i get full path like `http://localhost/abc`
(abc is a folder, in www directory)

Comment: not clear at all.abc is your folder name or url parameter ? and the page your getting folder is in same directory or somewhere else.

Comment: @MahmoodRehman abc is the folder what i create on www

Comment: `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];`

Comment: @scrowler thanks, your comment 5/5 helpful

Answer (score 2):

call this function and it will return the url

```
public function curPageURL() 
{
    $pageURL = 'http';
    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
    $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") 
    {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    } 
    else 
    {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }
    return $pageURL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do some coding to get it to work with [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).  So I would suggest this:

```
$parsed_url = parse_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
echo $parsed_url['path'];
```

But that would show the full path including the script name so you might have to add some logic to parse further.

EDIT: Decided to do some more coding on this concept & here is the result. Will return the path of the current script but without the script filename:

```
$parsed_url = parse_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$path_array = explode('/', $parsed_url['path']);
array_pop($path_array);
echo join('/', $path_array);
```